# OSX is ignoring my /etc/hosts *.dev domains

Tags: macos, dns

I have a vagrant box that gets setup with a lot of *.dev domains. However these does not work properly:

```
➜  ~  cat /etc/hosts

192.168.159.100 blabla.dev
```

When I ping the domain I get this:

```
PING spp.dev (127.0.53.53): 56 data bytes
```

As you may see, the request get sent to the ICANN domain collision address as mentioned in several other threads. However, my `/etc/hosts` is *NOT* a symlink but it's parent directory /etc seems to point towards /private/etc.

```
➜  ~  ls -la /etc
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Oct  9 15:49 /etc -> private/etc
```

I would be very thankful if someone with more knowledge about this can help me get the domain working. I am running **OSX Yosemite 10.10.1**. I have tried this in Firefox and Chrome and both are trying to access the wrong ip.

Comment: `blabla.dev`? `spp.dev`? Which is it?

Comment: Try printing it with `cat -vet /etc/hosts` -- make sure you don't have any spurious invisible characters in there (like "^M"), and that each line ends with "$" (even the last one). Also, you should have the regular localhost and broadcasthost entries in addition to the .dev entry.

Comment: Same here, did you find a way out?